# ((A → B) ∧ (A → C)) → D , B ∧ C ⊢ D

Tags: logic

((A > B) and (A > C)) > D :PR
B and C :PR

These are the premises ^^ I just need the inbetween. Like explain the tree/how to get to the goal of D

Comment: Unpack $B \land C$ to get $B$ and $C$ separately. From them, you can derive both $(A \to B)$ and $(A \to C)$.

Comment: Hi Ava, welcome to MSE. 
Have you discussed the truth table?

Answer (score 0):

One of your premises, $((A\to B)\land(A\to C))\to D$, is a conditional statement with $D$ as the consequent.

This should indicate to you that Conditional Elimination (aka *modus ponens*) may be the way you go.

That would be possible if you could derive $(A\to B)\land(A\to C)$ from the remaining premise: $B\land C$.

The path to doing so should be clear.